# Can I stack different javascript methods together in one function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Below will be an example of my code:

```
return input.split(" ").join("").sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
```

Just want to know whether or not I can 'stack' methods like this?

Comment: It depends what the methods return. [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on a string returns an array, on which you can use any array method (like [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)). However, as `join` on an array returns a string, which *doesn't* have a `sort` method, it will break at that point.

Comment: yes, you can chain functions. as long as the data type has the function you are using as you chain through

Comment: What happens when you do this? Does it give the result you want? Ultimately running code determines what you can and cannot do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called "method chaining" (or often just "chaining") and yes, it's perfectly normal.

Note that each method in the chain is making use of the return value of the previous method, so you can only do this when the previous method returns something you want to call a method on. For instance, your code above fails because `join` returns a string, but strings don't have a `sort` method:

```js
const input = "this is a test testing one two three";
console.log(
    input.split(" ").join("").sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5) // Error
);
```

But if you moved the `.join("")` to the end, it would work. You'd probably want `.join(" ")` though, rather than `.join("")`:

```js
const input = "this is a test testing one two three";
console.log(
    input.split(" ").sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).join(" ")
);
```

That works because:

- I've assumed `input` is a string
- Strings have a `split` method that returns an array
- Arrays have a `sort` method that returns the array you call it on
- Arrays have a `join` method that joins the entries together into a string